# openshift Gear postreceive Error in python django

Tags: django, python-2.7, openshift

I deployed my django application at

**django-appspot.rhcloud.com**

Until yesterday everything was working fine. But later when I pushed my codes I found errors on the deploy script in the action hooks near

**"$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/openshift/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"**

Here is my error message i received on pushing the codes.

**https://gist.github.com/maksudc/5894335**

Here is the build Script:

**https://gist.github.com/maksudc/5894366**

It says that Resource Manager instance has no attribute '_warn_unsafe_extraction'

But until yesterday everything was working fine.

Currently my application is stopped . I couldn't start it . Even if it doesn't fixed. I need to download my media directory .

What can I do ??

Comment: ->I sshed into the app 

-> Installed distribute and PIP

-> started the app by command

ctrl_app start


However it seems I need to do it everytime I push my codes. Please specify some solution so that I could work swiftly like before.

For the time being it might be a way to go with.

We are in a plan to upgrade our account to premium but such incidents are making us think again .

Comment: Can you write up a bug report on this issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading setuptools to 0.6c11.

I had the same issue in my project after upgrading setuptools to 0.7.5, so this appears to be an issue with that version.

(If anyone can shed some more light on the how and why, that would be nice)

Comment: Downgrading to 0.7.2 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem and posted to the Openshift Forum:

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/python-app-crashes-with-new-setuptools-v075

The issue was solved by rebuilding the virtualenv. You can to this by adding the force_clean_build marker in ./openshift/markers in your repo and then doing a git push. My app now works with setuptools 0.7.7.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your solution.

I think Openshift authority has downgraded  setuptools to 0.6.c11

So now I can again push my codes swiftly.

I have ssh into the server and checked what version it is currently using . I found setuptools 0.6c11